# Google blocking my java application to send mails(JavaMail). com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldnt connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com

Tags: java, email, security, jakarta-mail

In my java application I use JavaMail to send emails about application updates. Yesterday, I tried to send an email from the application but the connection was failed. At the same time I received an email from Google stating **Sign-in Attempt was blocked** *I was just working on an email program that read emails from Gmail and does further processing.* It says that my application is less secure hence it blocked the access. So I enabled **Allow access to Less secure apps: ON**(suggested by Google) although it is not recommended. Even after that I was unable to establish successful connection.

Below is the piece of code I'm using to connect:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
      return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
   }  
});
        
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host,  username, password);
```

Below is the exception I'm getting:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldnt connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465 timeout -1
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

There are some questions related to this issue this but none of them has proper solution and they are pretty old(2012 or 2014's). I think Google security norms must have changed by now. Please put on your thoughts on how to solve this issue.

Can you also suggest me, How to make my java application more secure?